# Computed properties are not reacting to state change

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, state, vuex, store

I am working on a product overview page, that send out an API-call based on the current Category you are looking at:

```
    store.dispatch("tweakwise/fetchAPIAttributesLayeredNavigation", {
     tweakwiseCategory,
     this.pageNumber,
}
```

In my Store, the data from this API-call will be set in the following VueX Store State:

```
this.$store.state.tweakwise.tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes: []
```

I want to react to this data in my front-end but my Computed methods do not seem to react to this change. As you can also see in the function below I added a Catch to prevent a "Non defined" error. The function, however, will not be called after the state has been set.
This computed property is also added to the Mount() op the component

```
computed: {
    initialFetchProducts() {
      this.fetchProducts(
        this.$store.state.tweakwise?.tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes || []
      );
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make computed property for state you want to watch,
than create watch() for this prop. In watch you can react on computed property change.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="product in products"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    return {
      products: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes() {
      return this.$store.state.tweakwise.tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    // on every tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes change we call fetchProducts
    tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes: {
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.fetchProducts(newValue);
      },
      deep: true, // necessary for watching Arrays, Object
      immediate: true, // will be fired like inside mounted()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchProducts(params) {
      const products = await axios.get('/api', params);
      this.products = products;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: and then just use the watcher like so:
          <ul
            v-for="filter in tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes"
            :key="filter.index"
          >

? Or how would you implement this?

Comment: Is this how you use this reactive flow in your own project(s) as well?

Comment: I dont know your particulat case, but yes, i am doing  something like that when i want to rerender list depend on some prop